# images cutted if outside the view

Tags: android, view, imageview, crop

I'm trying to put half image outside the view (via margins or anything else), to create a design.
The problem is that the image, is being cutted because i think android cut out the data outside the view.

Any ideas? An example image i've done:

[image]

And the image remain cropped (it's not half not visible)

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titoletti"
    android:id="@+id/parametri"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:id="@+id/CFLimite2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sotto_azzurro"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your code? And in app screenshot if possible. If red area is your landscape screen view. It might be because of margin/padding or layout implementation.

Comment: Without your XML's it's hard to tell what exactly is going on, but if the red blob is some kind of view group you may want to set `android:clipChildren="false"` on it. It's probably cleaner to stick the red blob and the blue blob in a common parent view group and arrange the alignment in that way.

Comment: my view parent is a relativelayout il fill_parent for both height and width. but i have edited the question posting the code.

Comment: well, the "view" in my image is the mail relativelayout, the screen of the phone in other word....